# how to define route in codeigniter i am trying but it not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Student';
$route['admin'] = 'index.php/Admin_depart/index';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

I am fairly new to CodeIgniter and finishing up my first project. However, before I put it up on my hosting site I would like to clean up the URL's using the routes.php file that CodeIgniter provides in the config folder. but it is not working it work correctly when i write same url i the default_controller

Answer (score 1):

The `index.php` is causing the issue.

Route destinations must be defined only as a `controller/method` pair. So in your case the correct route would be:

```
$route['admin'] = 'Admin_depart/index';
```

anyone browsing to `yoursite.com/admin` would be served whatever is in your `Admin_depart` controller, `index` method (just as if he/she browsed directly to `yoursite.com/admin_depart/index`;